# How to add WPF button to each WPF DataGrid column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, wpf-style

I have a WPF Datagrid style in my project. Now I want to add some buttons to each row, on the other hand, I want to be set the specific style to the buttons.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryRegionBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="EnableRowVirtualization" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="RowHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowHeaderStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"/>
        <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*"/>
        <Setter Property="hc:DataGridAttach.TextColumnStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="hc:DataGridAttach.EditingTextColumnStyle" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="hc:DataGridAttach.ComboBoxColumnStyle" Value="{StaticResource TextBlockComboBoxStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="hc:DataGridAttach.EditingComboBoxColumnStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBaseStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="hc:DataGridAttach.CheckBoxColumnStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxBaseStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="hc:DataGridAttach.EditingCheckBoxColumnStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxBaseStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="hc:DataGridAttach.ApplyDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.2" Value=".8"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.2" Value=".8"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.2" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.2" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Margin="0,0,0,6" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid},Converter={StaticResource DoubleMinConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonIcon}" hc:IconElement.Geometry="{StaticResource AllGeometry}" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryBrush}"/>
                                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <ScrollBar Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarBaseStyle}" Opacity="0" x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                        <ScrollBar Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarBaseStyle}" Opacity="0" x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard2}"/>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

as you see there are some styles for Texts or ComboBox but there is no style for buttons.
How can I add buttons to each row and set the specific button style?

Answer (score 0):

First part of your question

> How to add a button for each row in a Wpf datagrid ?

That's how you add a `button` foreach row in a `WPF DataGrid`.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
      <Button Click="BtnClicked">Details</Button> 
    </DataTemplate> 
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So, you create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and inside that you define `DataTemplate` and Inside that you can set `Button` or any other UI Element you want to show for each row e.g a `CheckBox`.

Now, Coming to second part of your question.

> How to add a particular style to it ?

Well you can define style for this button like any other button you do or you can assign it a `Style` resource or template. Something like below,

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
      <Button Click="BtnClicked" Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="2" BorderColor="Black">Details</Button> 
    </DataTemplate> 
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Or assign a style resource.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
      <Button Click="BtnClicked" Style="MyBtnStyle">Details</Button> 
    </DataTemplate> 
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```